# How can I have Chrome download images to a temp folder that's immediately cleared?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, images

At my job, we originally used Internet Explorer; when clicking on a certain link in a member's account, IE would prompt to Open or Save an associated image file. When Open was clicked, IE would open the image in a viewer, save the file (usually a .tif) to a temporary folder that was immediately deleted, which is the desired outcome; the image would remain open in the viewer, and when the viewer was closed, the image didn't remain on the hard drive.

We just switched to Chrome, and Chrome is saving files to the default download location (right now, the download folder). Even when I select "Always Open Files of this Type," Chrome still saves a copy to Downloads. The organization opens hundreds to thousands of files like these daily, and storing every one opened locally is neither feasible nor purposeful.

Is there a way to tell Chrome to essentially behave like IE did, with the download to an immediately deleted temp folder?

Comment: Why don't you ask your IT department? They are responsible for configuring Chrome correctly for their users.

Comment: you can do those tasks with chrome.downloads API : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads ; if your ok with it then i will add the details